# Message trying to append image to a list: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000181595FEF90>

Tags: python

I am trying to append the images to a list using a loop but I'm getting this error

> cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000181595FEF90>

My code:

```
data=[]
labels=[]

for i in imagepaths:
    label=i.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)
    print(i)
    image=load_img(i,target_size=(224,224))
    
    image=img_to_array(image)
    image=preprocess_input(image)
    data.append(image)
```

Comment: please share your entire code, what does the `load_img` function do?

Comment: Does the error "happen before" or after `print(i)`? What is the "label" printed, does it look OK?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.